# How to disable auto-repeated key events in tv-container

Tags: keyboard-events, google-tv, google-closure, google-closure-library

Is there a way to disable auto-repeated key events? Specifically I'm using the closure google tv web ui library, and when holding down/up scrolling through the components of a tv-container-vertical I'd like it to only move one at a time, regardless of whether the key is pressed or held.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it's not trivial to do. You will need to define the key behavior with your own handler which would override the GTV provided closure lib code for key navigation.